# Latex table: text does not center on cell

Tags: tables, color, multirow, cell

I'm trying to create a table in Latex, but the text does not line up in the center of the cell, in some cells, and leaves out of the table. How can I solve the problem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{AAE3F4} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Parcerias-chave}                                                                                                & {\color[HTML]{000000} Atividades-chave}                                                                                                                 & {\color[HTML]{000000} Propostas de valor}                                                                                                                                                                                                              & {\color[HTML]{000000} Relações com os clientes}                                                                                                                     & {\color[HTML]{000000} Segmentos de mercado}                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
                                                                                                                                      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Prospeção de novos\\ clientes, fazer o \\ gerenciamento\\ dos canais de \\ divulgação, \\ divulgação da oferta.\end{tabular} &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Contacto através de e-mail, \\ newsletter, atendimento ao \\ cliente.\end{tabular}                                                       &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
                                                                                                                                      & \cellcolor[HTML]{AAE3F4}Recursos-chave                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{AAE3F4}Canais                                                                                                                                      &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
\multirow{-3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Empresas logísticas,\\ empresas parceiras\\ que desejem ser\\ publicitadas.\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Plataformas de \\ comunicação\\ e de notoriedade.\end{tabular}                                                               & \multirow{-3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Descontos em \\ ocasiões especiais, \\ descontos para \\ clientes fidelizados,\\ descontos na aquisição\\ de grandes quantidades,\\  ação promocional de compra\\  de publicidade + produto.\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Redes sociais (Facebook, \\ Instagram, Twitter, etc), \\ Youtube, venda online, \\ feiras de exposição, \\ locais de venda.\end{tabular} & \multirow{-3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Portadores de \\ deficiência motora, \\ que não lhes permite\\ carregar grandes pesos\\  e que gostariam de ter\\  uma maior autonomia \\ e uma melhor \\ qualidade de vida.\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{AAE3F4} 
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{AAE3F4}Estrutura de custos}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{AAE3F4}Fonte de rendimento}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Pagamentos diretos e online, equipamentos e funcionários.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Venda do produto online e cross-promotion.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: You never should use `\resizebox`  for table, as it leads to font size inconsistencies. Do you really want each line in multiline cells to be centred horizontally?

Comment: To clarify, your text is already horizontally centered because of the `c`, but you are also trying to get it to be vertically centered?

Comment: @Teepeemm My problem is that below the cell that says "Value Proposals" (for example), the text goes out of the cell and I wanted it to be centered in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

This type of tabulars are easy to build if you use [a calstable from the package cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals). I enclose two examples of your tabular, since I was unsure which layout you asked for. Also, I assumed the different column width was intentionally:

### Example 1

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cals, xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\definecolor{ligthBlue}{HTML}{AAE3F4}

\let\nc=\nullcell                              % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}
\footnotesize                                  % Necessary to reduce size 
\begin{calstable}

% Defining column relative to each other and relative to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/50*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/50*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/50*11\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/50*11\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/50*10\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills the text area

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.2pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.2pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.2pt}    % Rule between heading and body
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.2pt}        % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.2pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}

\def\blue{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty % THis is a macro that switch on or off colour
\def\cals@bgcolor{ligthBlue}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Botton border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}          % To remove rules in cells
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

% R1
\thead{\blue
\brow
    \alignC\cell{Parcerias-chave}
    \cell{Atividades-chave}
    \cell{Propostas de valor}
    \cell{Relações com os clientes}
    \cell{Segmentos de mercado}
\erow
\blue}
% R2 Body
\brow
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{\vfil Prospeção de novos clientes, fazer o gerenciamento dos canais de divulgação,  divulgação da oferta.}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{\vfil Contacto através de e-mail, newsletter, atendimento ao cliente.}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
\erow

% R3 Body
\brow
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \blue\cell{Recursos-chave}\blue
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \blue\cell{Canais}\blue
    \bb\cell{}\bb
\erow
% R4 Body
\brow
    \cell{\vfil Empresas logísticas, empresas parceiras que desejem ser publicitadas.}
    \cell{\vfil Plataformas de  comunicação e de notoriedade.}
    \cell{\vfil Descontos em ocasiões especiais, descontos para clientes fidelizados, descontos na aquisição de grandes quantidades,  ação promocional de compra  de publicidade + produto.}
    \cell{\vfil Redes sociais (Facebook,  Instagram, Twitter, etc), Youtube, venda online, feiras de exposição, locais de venda.}
    \cell{\vfil Portadores de deficiência motora, que não lhes permite carregar grandes pesos  e que gostariam de ter uma maior autonomia e uma melhor qualidade de vida}
\erow
% R5 Body
\brow
    \blue\nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{\vfil Estrutura de custos}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{\vfil Fonte de rendimento}\blue
\erow
% R6 Body
\brow
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{\vfil Pagamentos diretos e online, equipamentos e funcionários.}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{\vfil Venda do produto online e cross-promotion.}
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par % \par to align the tabular
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Example 2

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cals, xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\definecolor{ligthBlue}{HTML}{AAE3F4}


\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{calstable}

% Defining column relativ to each other and relativ to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/50*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/50*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/50*11\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/50*11\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/50*10\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills the text area

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.2pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.2pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.2pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.2pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.2pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}

\def\blue{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
\def\cals@bgcolor{ligthBlue}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

% R1
\thead{\blue
\brow
    \alignC\cell{Parcerias-chave}
    \cell{Atividades-chave}
    \cell{Propostas de valor}
    \cell{Relações com os clientes}
    \cell{Segmentos de mercado}
\erow
\blue}
% R2 Body
\brow
    \nc{lrt}
    \cell{\vfil Prospeção de novos clientes, fazer o gerenciamento dos canais de divulgação,  divulgação da oferta.}
    \nc{lrt}
    \cell{\vfil Contacto através de e-mail, newsletter, atendimento ao cliente.}
    \nc{lrt}
\erow

% R3 Body
\brow
    \nc{lr}
    \blue\cell{Recursos-chave}\blue
    \nc{lr}
    \blue\cell{Canais}\blue
    \nc{lr}
\erow
% R4 Body
\brow
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil Empresas logísticas, empresas parceiras que desejem ser publicitadas.}
    \cell{\vfil Plataformas de  comunicação e de notoriedade.}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil Descontos em ocasiões especiais, descontos para clientes fidelizados, descontos na aquisição de grandes quantidades,  ação promocional de compra  de publicidade + produto.}
    \cell{\vfil Redes sociais (Facebook,  Instagram, Twitter, etc), Youtube, venda online, feiras de exposição, locais de venda.}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil Portadores de deficiência motora, que não lhes permite carregar grandes pesos  e que gostariam de ter uma maior autonomia e uma melhor qualidade de vida}
\erow
% R5 Body
\brow
    \blue\nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{\vfil Estrutura de custos}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{\vfil Fonte de rendimento}\blue
\erow
% R6 Body
\brow
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{\vfil Pagamentos diretos e online, equipamentos e funcionários.}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{\vfil Venda do produto online e cross-promotion.}
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par % \par to align the tabular

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I propose this simpler code with `tabularx`  and `hhline`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx, hhline}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering\footnotesize
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{5}{X|}}
\hhline{-----}
\rowcolor[HTML]{AAE3F4}
\multirow{2}{*}{Parcerias-chave} & \multirow{2}{*}{Atividades-chave} & \multirow{2}{*}{Propostas de valor} & Relações com os clientes & Segmentos de mercado \\ \hline
 & Prospeção de novos clientes, fazer o gerenciamento dos canais de divulgação, divulgação da oferta. %
 & & Contacto através de e-mail, newsletter, atendimento ao cliente. & \\ & & & & \\[-1.5ex]
 \hhline{~|-~|-~}
 & \cellcolor[HTML]{AAE3F4}Recursos-chave & & \cellcolor[HTML]{AAE3F4}Canais & \\[0.5ex] %
 \hhline{~|-~|-~}
 Empresas logísticas, empresas parceiras que desejem ser publicitadas%
 & Plataformas de comunicação e de notoriedade. %
 & Descontos em ocasiões especiais, descontos para clientes fidelizados, descontos na aquisição de grandes quantidades, ação promocional de compra de publicidade + produto. & Redes sociais (Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, etc.), Youtube, venda online, feiras de exposição, locais de venda.%
 & Portadores de deficiência motora, que não lhes permite carregar grandes pesos e que gostariam de ter uma maior autonomia e uma melhor qualidade de vida. \\ & & & & \\[-1.5ex]
\hhline{-----}
\rowcolor[HTML]{AAE3F4}
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Estrutura de custos} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Fonte de rendimento} \\[0.5ex]
\hhline{-----}
\multicolumn{3}{|p{\dimexpr0.6 \linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{Pagamentos diretos e online, equipamentos e funcionários.} & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr0.4\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Venda do produto online e {cross-promotion}.} \\
\hhline{-----}
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Bernard suggestion is better than what I suggested, so I've removed my answer....